# MS Access scrollbar on subform continuous forms not setting record focus

Tags: ms-access, vba

I can't seem to figure this out.  I have a subform displaying continuous forms with a vertical scrollbar.  When I click the scrollbar to move to a different record, the record never receives focus.  The focus is still on the control of the record I left.

How to I control the record focus after using the scrollbar?  The subform's On Current event does not fire.

Thanks!

Comment: You just learn how Access works ?

Comment: this is the whole Windows way of working, like it or not. You highlight something in any app, then you scroll, that does not have any impact on your selection. If you don't want that, look for another OS. And if you want to build an app that does behave like it should, well...I think you shouldn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The vertical scroll bar in a continuous MS Access form does not *navigate* among records.  It simply changes which records are visible on the form.  The black triangle within the record selector on the left side of the form indicates which record is currently "selected."

You can navigate records (ie, control the record focus, as you say) several different ways:

- Click on the record selector* (the gray rectangle to the left of the form detail section)
- Click on any enabled control within the form detail section
- Use the navigation controls* at the bottom left of the form
- Use [Tab], [Enter], or arrow keys to move through the individual controls on the form detail section; when you reach the last control in the tab order, your next [Tab]/[Enter]/[Down Arrow] key press will take you to the next record

* Note that both the Record Selectors and Navigation Buttons may be turned off on your form.  On the form property sheet, ensure `Record Selectors: Yes` and `Navigation Buttons: Yes`.

Comment: Well, I have the record selector and nav buttons off.  I've created my own nav buttons to limit what can be done by the user.  For the specific form I have, a scroll bar is handy for the user to quickly get to a record.  I was just hoping there was a way to get some response from the scrollbar to know when it was changing record views in order to make that specific record active.

Comment: Yes.  There is a way to indicate which record is active.  It's called the record selector.  Is there some sample user interface you are trying to replicate?  It seems like you are fighting against the current by trying to work around all of Access's default behavior.  If we knew the end-state we could provide better help.

Comment: But using the record selector still requires the user to click on it in order to make the visible record active.  Plus, it opens up a bunch of other options I don't want the user to have.  I simply want whatever record is showing to have focus.  I've decided not to use the scroll bar.  It's unfortunate that the scrollbar has no events of it's own to trap.

Thanks for your help, though.  I do appreciate it. :-)

Comment: What options do you think showing the record selector opens up?  Simply displaying the record selector provides no additional options to the user.  That is why that property is on the Format tab of the property sheet and not the Data tab.

Comment: Pardon me.  I stand corrected. I thought the record selector allowed the user to do things like Delete the record, etc.  I decided not to use the scroll bar and do things differently anyway.  Thanks for all your help.